# What's this sensor called? Found it in my AC unit

Tags: sensor

It's a 2 wire sensor I found in my central home air-conditioning unit. Any ideas what it's called? Wasn't able to find a part number on it.

Is there a test I can do to find out, using a multimeter?

[image: Unknown sensor]
[image: Unknown sensor - 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it could either be a thermocouple or thermistor. The copper sheathing exists to protect the sensor inside. Many thermistors use a glass-covered sensor which can be easily damaged. A thermocouple generates (mVs of) voltage and a thermistor changes its resistance. If you have a multimeter, measuring the resistance across its wires can determine what it is. A thermistor will read a certain resistance, depending on the temperature. Common values include ~10K and ~100K Ω, but it may vary. A thermocouple will give anything else. Many multimeters have a thermocouple mode, but only for specific types, and probing the sensor is not very easy. Posting a picture of the connector may help identify the sensor, as many thermocouples use standard connectors.

However, as Dmitri and Nick mention in the comments, a thermocouple is unlikely due to noise in motors interfering and the lack of color-coded wires.

Comment: Thanks! I have a multimeter handy -- will test both V and R..

Comment: my guess would be a thermistor. theres a bunch of high-power machinery around it that would interfere with the signal of a thermocouple.

Comment: maybe something like this? http://www.semitec.co.jp/english/products/thermo/thermistor-sensor/kyutou/

Comment: I would rule out thermocouple.  Thermocouples almost always have [color-coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple#Comparison_of_types) leads.

Comment: @FloatingRock without specialized connectors, measuring mV will likely only give noise & inconsistent results.

Comment: "A thermistor will read from 10K to 100K Ω" It could also be a RTD at e.g. 100 Ω. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer

Comment: The resistance range for a thermistor will vary depending on its intended use. It doesn't need to be between 10K and 100K, it could be 100 ohm to 1K, or 3K to 10K, or whatever. If the temperature changes steadily (either up or down) when you hold it tightly in your hand, it is probably a thermistor

Comment: @DerStrom8 true, but 10K and 100K are common values, at least in my experience.

Comment: They may be common but that does not mean that if it measures outside of that range that it is not a thermistor. Your comment suggested that if it does not measure between 10K and 100K then it is not a thermistor which is absolutely not the case.

Comment: Thermistor/RTD it is folks! Definitely noted a change in resistance when I held it in my hands .. it reads ~1.2k ohm at ambient, but it could be faulty because this was the unit my handyman replaced. Thanks!

Comment: @FloatingRock as others have mentioned, it may read a different value (I just wrote those values based on experience). Putting it in cold/hot water may vary the resistance.